# URLWithString returns nil for resource path - iphone

Tags: iphone, resources, nsurl

Having a problem getting the URL for a resource for some reason:  This code is in viewDidLoad, and it's worked in other applications, but not here for some reason:

```
NSString* audioString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"wav"];
NSLog(@"AUDIO STRING: %@" , audioString);

NSURL* audioURL = [NSURL URLWithString:audioString];
NSLog(@"AUDIO URL: %d" , audioURL);

NSError* playererror;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&playererror];
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];    

NSLog(@"Error %@", playererror);
```

**LOG OUTPUT:**

AUDIO STRING: /var/mobile/Applications/D9FA0569-45FF-4287-8448-7EA21E92EADC/SoundApp.app/sound.wav

AUDIO URL: 0

Error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "Operation could not be completed. (OSStatus error -50.)"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your string has no protocol, so it's an invalid [url](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator).  Try this...

```
NSString* expandedPath = [audioString stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSURL* audioUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:expandedPath];
```

Comment: sorry, i abbreviated the log entry, but the string is a valid path and using the expanded path doesn't make a difference

Comment: ah sorry again, I should have read this more carefully.  Changing to fileURLWithPath did fix the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Just change one line to this:

```
    NSURL* audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioString];
```

Answer (score 4):

You're passing `audioURL` in your `NSLog` method as `%d` hence why you get 0.  If you pass it as an object with `%@` you'll get `NULL`.

Try passing into the audioplayer like this and skip the string.

```
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"wav"]];
```

Comment: my original call was [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"wav"]] error:nil]; but I still had the same problem; I just split it up for easier debugging

Answer (score 2):

You aren't reading the responses carefully enough - you are using URLWithString, when you should use fileURLWithPath.  You can't pass a file:// path to URLWithString.  I think you also need to prepend file:// at the front of the string as you have only a path (which as pointed out has no protocol).