# Data is always null... no idea why

Tags: ios, nsdata, nsurl, mp4

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mp4"];

NSLog(@"Path: %@", path);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSLog(@"Data exists? %@", data ? @"yes" : @"no");
```

test.mp4 is in my bundle, but this is always the output

```
2013-03-13 11:50:29.444 videoAppPrototype[28625:907] Path: /var/mobile/Applications/D66DD820-4DE1-4E45-9495-9BACF130E368/videoAppPrototype.app/test.mp4
2013-03-13 11:50:29.446 videoAppPrototype[28625:907] URL: /var/mobile/Applications/D66DD820-4DE1-4E45-9495-9BACF130E368/videoAppPrototype.app/test.mp4
2013-03-13 11:50:29.448 videoAppPrototype[28625:907] Data exists? no
```

I don't know why, but the data never exists.

Comment: And you are sure `test.mp4` exists in the app bundle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [URLWithString returns nil for resource path - iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112927/urlwithstring-returns-nil-for-resource-path-iphone)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're retrieving a file path and then using it for a URL. You either want to retrieve a URL and use a URL:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"mp4"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Or you want to retrieve a path and use a path:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

As bgoers points out, if you have a path and need a file URL, you can use `fileURLWithPath`, though I'd rather use one of the two above techniques. Anyway, to use `fileURLWithPath`, it is as follows:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Comment: Can you explain why it would fail though?  The URL appears correct.

Comment: Long story short, you can't mix URLs and file paths very well in iOS :)

Comment: I believe he could also use `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]` to go down the URL route. But best to use one of the above two methods.

Comment: @trojanfoe The URL from `URLForResource` starts with `file://localhost/` followed by the path. When you just retrieve a path, you're missing that. The result of `pathForResource` is not a valid URL string.

Comment: Looks like you are correct, but I find it surprising that `dataWithContentsOfURL` doesn't assume the `file:` scheme if it's missing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112927/urlwithstring-returns-nil-for-resource-path-iphone

Comment: @Rob Yeah I know; that's why this question is a dupe.