# AVPlayer with local video file

Tags: ios, nsurl

There is a little video part in my application.

So i find this sample, which play mp4 video from url: http://www.sdkboy.com/?p=66

You can download sample here: http://www.sdkboy.com/tutorials/AVFoundation_Test3.zip

But when I replace NSURL code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.samkeeneinteractivedesign.com/videos/littleVid3.mp4"];
```

With this one, for playing local video, player doesn't work.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"malina36" ofType:@"mp4"]];
```

This file exist, i check it with

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:url.absoluteString]) {
        NSLog(@"yes");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"no");
    }
```

Can you help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [URLWithString returns nil for resource path - iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112927/urlwithstring-returns-nil-for-resource-path-iphone)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using [fileURLWithPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method instead of URLWithString: